# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_compiler_dispatch'

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am using the `flask-sqlalchemy` extension with `alembic` for migrations. When I try to add a new migration file and upgrade the schema to the latest one, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_compiler_dispatch'
```

The content of the migration file:

```
revision = 'ec2c2d40eb1'
down_revision = '28dda873b826'

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    op.alter_column(
        'users',
        'wiki_permission',
        new_column_name='wiki_group',
        nullable=False,
        existing_nullable=False,
        type_=sa.Integer(),
        existing_type=sa.Integer(),
        server_default=1,
        existing_server_default=1          # Line of error - 27
    )   


def downgrade():
    op.alter_column(
        'users',
        'wiki_group',
        new_column_name='wiki_permission',
        nullable=False,
        existing_nullable=False,
        type_=sa.Integer(),
        existing_type=sa.Integer(),
        server_default=1,
        existing_server_default=1
    )
```

Thanks for taking time to help me.

**Edit:**

The complete error message :

```
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade 28dda873b826 -> ec2c2d40eb1, users change column wiki_permission to wiki_group
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/bin/alembic", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('alembic==0.6.5', 'console_scripts', 'alembic')()
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 298, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 293, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 279, in run_cmd
    **dict((k, getattr(options, k)) for k in kwarg)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 125, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/script.py", line 203, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/util.py", line 212, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/compat.py", line 58, in load_module_py
    mod = imp.load_source(module_id, path, fp)
  File "alembic/env.py", line 77, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "alembic/env.py", line 70, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 7, in run_migrations
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/environment.py", line 688, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/migration.py", line 258, in run_migrations
    change(**kw)
  File "alembic/versions/ec2c2d40eb1_users_change_column_wiki_permission_to_.py", line 27, in upgrade
    existing_server_default=1,
  File "<string>", line 7, in alter_column
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/util.py", line 329, in go
    return fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/operations.py", line 317, in alter_column
    existing_autoincrement=existing_autoincrement
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/mysql.py", line 44, in alter_column
    else existing_autoincrement
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 76, in _exec
    conn.execute(construct, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 720, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 67, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 768, in _execute_ddl
    compiled = ddl.compile(dialect=dialect)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 468, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 25, in _compiler
    return dialect.ddl_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 197, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 220, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/compiler.py", line 410, in <lambda>
    lambda *arg, **kw: existing(*arg, **kw))
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/compiler.py", line 448, in __call__
    return fn(element, compiler, **kw)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/mysql.py", line 171, in _mysql_change_column
    autoincrement=element.autoincrement
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/mysql.py", line 190, in _mysql_colspec
    spec += " DEFAULT %s" % _render_value(compiler, server_default)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/mysql.py", line 179, in _render_value
    return compiler.sql_compiler.process(expr)
  File "/home/kevin/Code/python/flask/terminus/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 220, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_compiler_dispatch'
```

Comment: There may be other problems. I don't believe you want the parens/brackets after `sa.Integer`. I.e. it should just be: `type_=sa.Integer,` and similar for next line. Also adding the line of the error would help.

Comment: @bernie the brackets don't seem to be a problem. I've updated the question with the error line (27).

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. I would try without the parens/brackets after `sa.Integer`. Often the line of the error is further down from the actual problem code.

Comment: @bernie It throws the same error even after removing the brackets after `sa.Integer`.

Comment: Alright. I was "tilting at windmills". Thanks for the update. I will noodle on this a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I just went through this same issue. I'm not using flask-sqlalchemy, just straight alembic, but it should be identical.

1. Second, it worked for me with `sa.Integer` with no parentheses, so I would recommend that.
2. The [alembic docs](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column) say:

   > When producing MySQL-compatible migration files, it is recommended that the existing_type, existing_server_default, and existing_nullable parameters be **present, if not being altered**.

   Since it seems you are **not** altering these columns, the docs suggest they should be present. So:

   - Remove `nullable`, `type_`, and `server_default`. They are not being altered.
   - Keep `existing_nullable`, `existing_type`, and `existing_server_default`.